# program nav menu in react. How do I use logical statements to display html?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, nav

I'm using gatsby.js to make a site and using graphql to pull in data for a menu.  The menu data is working fine however when I try to add a submemu with logical conditions it outputs the html instead of rendering it.  So instead of showing the unordered submenu list, it outputs `<ul>` and `</ul>` on my site. (where the list items and main ul are working fine)

Here is my menu component code:

```
const WPMenu = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query ={ graphql`
    {
      wordpressMenusMenusItems(name: {eq: "Main Menu"}) {
        name
        items {
          slug
          title
          child_items {
            slug
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }`
    }
    render = { data => (
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          {data.wordpressMenusMenusItems.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.title}>
              {item.child_items ? <Link aria-haspopup="true" to={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link> : <Link to={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</Link>}
              {item.child_items ? '<ul>' : "" } //this line is not working
              {item.child_items && item.child_items.map ( child => 
                  <li key={child.title}><Link to={`/${child.slug}`} >{child.title}</Link></li>
              )}
              {item.child_items ? '</ul>' : "" }  //this line is not working
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )}
  />
);
```

its the two commented lines `{item.child_items ? '<ul>' : "" } //this line is not working`
That are giving me problems.

I've tried with this: `{item.child_items ? "<ul>" : "" }`

and replacing quotes with code ticks as well:

```
{item.child_items ? `<ul>` : "" }
```

I'm new to js, so likely there's something I'm missing, but why is it interpreting it as code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that is item.child_items is true if is an empty array `[]` since it is checking it reference exist or not;
you can use `item.child_items.length > 0` as the condition or simply `item.child_items.length`since 0 is equal to false in js `0 == false //true`

```
{item.child_items.length && '<ul>'}
```

or

```
{item.child_items.length > 0 ? '<ul>' : ''}
```

check the snippet for more info:

```js
const obj = { items : [] }

//even though it is empty it will give you true;
console.log( Boolean(obj.items) )
// not not something is boolean equivilant of that thing
console.log( !!obj.items )

//workaround? using length
//since 0 == false
console.log( "how about length?", Boolean(obj.items.length))
```

> Caveat: if `item.child_items` doesn't have length property, that line would throw an exception (e.g. item.child_items being `undefined` or `null`)